# Using PHP, Why can I not use $_GET to get a value from a URL if there is a _ in the URL?

Tags: php, url, get

I have this in my URL;

```
?utm_source=John%27s%20Source
```

I want to get the value using this;

```
echo rawurlencode(stripslashes($_GET['utm_source']));
```

That does not return anything. However, if I get rid of the _ on 'utmsource' in both the URL and the _GET, it will return this;

```
John%27s%20Source
```

Which is exactly what I am looking for. Why can I not do the same with the underscore?

Comment: What do you see in `var_dump($_GET)` or even `var_dump(array_keys($_GET))`? I can't see any reason why you can't use the get index like that.

Comment: didn't you post this already? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47422231/1415724

Comment: Fred,
I did post that, but that was a different issue I have since solved.

Comment: It looks like the previous question has the GET variable as simply "utmsource". Is it possible you've got a mix of "old" code and new? Like your <form> page has a target URL with `utmsource`, but the actual script looks for `utm_source`? A `var_dump` as @Scuzzy suggested would shed a lot of light on this.

Comment: @Scuzzy I have 5 variables in the URL that start with utm_
var_dump(array_keys($_GET)) will return all of them if none have an underscore, but if any do have an underscore it will only return the variables before the one with the underscore.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

So it turns out that by defualt WPEngine will not let you use '$*GET' with something that starts with "utm*". I guess this has to do with it being a Google search term and by default it is turned off. I found this thread and contacted WPEngine like the person in the thread, and now it works just fine.

Thanks for the help guys.

[Having "utm_" in the URL string breaks the $_GET variable in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567004/having-utm-in-the-url-string-breaks-the-get-variable-in-wordpress)