# PHP a param exists in URL but not in $_GET array?

Tags: php, get

I am facing this (I don't know what to call this) situation I have a URL like

```
site.com/?tag=value&other=1&more=2
```

the problem is that when i

```
var_dump($_GET);
// prints
array( 'other' => '1', 'more' => '2');
```

for some reason the parameter **tag** is missing from $_GET array.

any ideas? the server request_uri is

```
'REQUEST_URI' => string '/site-com/?other=1&more=2'
```

its even missing in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and the server is

```
Linux 4.4.216-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 x86_64
PHP 7.3
```

Thanks

Comment: PHP version ? Web server ? OS ? Weird behaviour.

Comment: Strange! Whats' the result of this : site.com/?other=1&more=2&tag=value

Comment: @AymDev, Yes that is why I said I don't know what to call this situation.

Comment: @Dri372 same the tag is missing, no matter where you put the tag it is still missing!

Comment: @AymDev, I updated the question its Linux and PHP 7.3

Comment: Having a look to your to REQUEST_URI, you should have a rewrite url somewhere ... are your using a framwork? have you a .httaccess? is-it in a virtualhost?

Comment: @Dri372 I think it's the host provider targets and removes it for performance issues.

Comment: What should be a performance issue with a tag in an url?

Comment: @Dri372 Godaddy does it with utm_campaign

Comment: and if you try to use a different order for those params, is it the same?

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi Yes no matter which order the tag is still missing.

Comment: There should no tag with the name 'tag' used by utm_compaign

Comment: @Dri372 its a Godaddy wordpress managed host, the tag is just an example the actual parameter is utm_campaign that is being missed from the $_GET array

Comment: the tag is just an example :-)

Comment: @Dri372, doing this for a client, he wants to pass the utm_campaign to all links in his webpage.

Comment: really a different question, you should close this one and open a new one ...

Comment: @Dri372 done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973999/php-parameter-utm-campaign-exists-in-url-but-not-in-get-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having "utm\_" in the URL string breaks the $\_GET variable in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567004/having-utm-in-the-url-string-breaks-the-get-variable-in-wordpress)

Comment: I strongly suggest you to contact your hosting service. I'm glad I don't have to use such services anymore, having even basic Linux skills can make you free.

Comment: @AymDev, no wpengine is not being used.

Comment: @codedudey just ignore my question, it was automatic as I flagged your question as a duplicate. It does not matter if the name of the hosting service is *wpengine*, *Godaddy* or even *codedudey*, contact them, the issue probably is on their side.

Answer (score 2):

This answer sumerize the discussion in comment.

This url `'REQUEST_URI' => string '/site-com/?other=1&more=2'`

suggests that there is some url rewriting somewhere, it can be done by the framework, web server settings (or .htaccess, virtualhost).

In this case, the queston was not enough clear, 'tag' is only an example, in fact in this OP 'tag' is utm_campaign and Godaddy filters these utm_ tags.