# PHP parameter utm_campaign exists in URL but not in $_GET array

Tags: php, get

I am facing this (I don't know what to call this) situation I have a URL like

```
site.com/?utm_campaign=value&other=1&more=2
```

the problem is that when i

```
var_dump($_GET);
// prints
array( 'other' => '1', 'more' => '2');
```

for some reason the parameter **utm_campaign** is missing from $_GET array.

any ideas? the server request_uri is

```
'REQUEST_URI' => string '/site-com/?other=1&more=2'
```

its even missing in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and the server is hosted in Godaddy and the WPEngine is not being used.

there is a javascript solutions in case some one else wanted to use but in my case I require it in php $_GET.

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var utm_campaign = url.searchParams.get("utm_campaign");
console.log(utm_campaign);
```

Comment: You have to precise taht your site is hosted (by godaddy)

Comment: @Dri372, thanks, added to question

Comment: And the answer is probably here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567004/having-utm-in-the-url-string-breaks-the-get-variable-in-wordpress ... I'll put my anser on the first one for you to be able to close the first post.

Comment: @Dri372, the WPEngine is not being used here.

Comment: OK, but I don't tthing it's relating/only with WPEngine ... we should do the test on other hosted site ... personnaly I don't use it, i host my servers (physicaly and on vps)